# Find a specific value in a object with key but i don't know the path

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this : 
That is just for example....

```
{a:"aaaa", 
 b:{ 
    b1:"1b1b1b", 
    b2:"2bb22b",
    b3:{
        mykey:"value to find",
        some:"same",
        },
    },
 }
```

I know the key "mykey" but I don't know where is it , I don't know the path...
I cant use like this to find the value...

```
myObj.a.b.maykey
```

because i don't know where is the key "mykey" 
I only know that I have in my object this Key

I have to find "value to find",
how can i find a value of myKey?

thanks

Comment: Do you know the *key* or the *value* for the key?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't make out what *"...i aonly know that o have in same place of my object ..."* means.

Comment: I'm sorry about the answers. I can see my question is wrongly formulated....That i need is find a a value in a object by key.... but I cant use path like "myObj.a.b.maykey" because i don't know the object,  i know only that I have myKey as key to find a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the key is `myKey` and you're looking for it somewhere in the object graph, one option is to use a depth-first traversal recursive function (similar to that used by the DOM for `querySelector`). This is much simpler than the name suggests. :-) See comments:

```js
function findFirstValue(data, key) {
    // ASSERTION: data is an object
    // Loop through the properties of the object
    for (const [name, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
        // Found the key?
        if (name === key) {
            // Return the value
            return value;
        }
        // If the value is an object, recurse
        if (typeof value === "object") {
            const found = findFirstValue(value, key);
            if (found !== undefined) {
                // Found during recursion
                return found;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Not found
    return undefined; // Explicit, but this is effectively what would happen anyway
}

const found = findFirstValue({
    a: "aaaa",
    b: {
        b1: "1b1b1b",
        b2: "2bb22b",
        b3: {
            mykey: "value",
            some: "same",
        },
    },
}, "mykey");
console.log(found);
```

That returns `undefined` if not found. You could use a flag value instead (so that if the key is found but the value actually is `undefined`, you can tell the difference). That's a minor tweak to the above. But if you can assume the value won't actually be `undefined`, `undefined` makes a good flag value to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by recursion.

```js
let obj = {a:"aaaa", 
 b:{ 
    b1:"1b1b1b", 
    b2:"2bb22b",
    b3:{
        mykey:"value",
        some:"same",
        },
    },
 }

function find(obj,givenKey){
  for(let key in obj){
    //checks if key's value is object 
    if(typeof obj[key] === "object"){ 
    //find 'givenKey' inside that object
      let keyValue = find(obj[key],givenKey)
      //if 'givenKey' is found in that object 
      if(keyValue){
        //return that key's value
        return keyValue
      }
    }
    //if key's value is not object 
    else{
      //if key match given key then it return the value of key
      if(key === givenKey) return obj[key]
    }
  }
}
console.log(find(obj,'mykey'))
```

Comment: I have error: Unexpected use of 'find'  no-restricted-globals

Comment: @Matteo Angelotti it is working fine in the snippet.